# An exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, data

Tengo el siguiente error cuando quiero hacer algo en mi web, levanta el front y back sin problemas, inicio sesión pero al querer entrar a algún módulo de la web, la pagina se queda cargando y me mando el error de la imagen.

Tengo instalado lo siguiente:

- ODAC122011_X64
- ODTWITHODAC122011
- ORACLE_WINX64_12102_CLIENT

Alguien tiene alguna solución? agradezco su ayuda

[image: Error que me aparece]